# Twitter Bootstrap 3 fixed navbar collapse in horizontal mode

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

Update: So, I totally misdiagnosed the problem. Looks like the collapse work fine as it should collapse on @grid-float-breakpoint which is set to @screen-sm-min but for some reason navbar is now **collapsed in horizontal mode**  by default. Which is what I am debugging right now.

The navbar collapse works fine on most resolutions. It collapse fine on extra small devices and shows up as expected on medium and large devices. but not for small resolutions such as an iPad (1024×768), the bar collapse but the icon doesn't show up!!!

Here is my code:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-inverse-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand"><img src='assets/logo.png'/></a>
  </div>
    <div class="navbar-inverse-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><%= link_to("Games", games_path) unless current_page?(games_path) %></li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right global-search">
          <input type="text" id="global-search" class="form-control col-lg-8" placeholder="Instant search">
      </form>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
</div>
```

Any idea why this is happening? Using tbs 3.2.0 on a Ruby on Rails 4.1 application

Comment: Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px). 
Small devices (tablets, 768px and up). 
Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up). 
Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up). 
source: http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Comment: Next time, google before you "Sheesh". Better yet, if you have a useless comment, keep it to yourself. Sheesh :D

Comment: Today's lesson is about Tablets. They come in **2** orientations. A portrait mode in which the smallest dimension become the width of the view. In the case of the iPad, it is 768 which fall into the Small devices (tablets, 768px and up). Did you get it yet? Or do you need a youtube video to teach you how to hold a tablet in 2 different orientations?

Comment: Good. I don't have time to waste trying to explain the obvious to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured out my issue. The collapsed area didn't have the "navbar-collapse" class in it which was needed for collapse to function properly.  So instead of:

```
<div class="navbar-inverse-collapse collapse">
```

It should have been:

```
<div class="navbar-inverse-collapse navbar-collapse collapse">
```

Comment: `navbar-inverse-collapse` presumably being some custom class you cooked up, since it's not part of Bootstrap.

Comment: Yes, I have multiple navbars in the same page. So, you need a unique class for each one in order to toggle them separately. Otherwise, clicking on a collapse icon will collapse all navbars. I should have used an id instead for clarification sake.

Answer (score 0):

When the navbar collapse the icon is 'removed'. Instead u see 3 lines(the default collapsed navbar icon) if u change that particular icon it will show up instead of the lines

Comment: No, that is not how it works. If the bar is collapsable, the icon will always show. clicking the icon will the show or hide the collapsed content. This is how it is working right now on extra small devices. Try resizing your window here to see the functionality: http://bootswatch.com/default/